# Automated numbers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a add more field. So when I press `add more` button it should add a number `1. textfield and a dropdown menu`. and if you press once more it should do `2. textfield and a dropdown menu`.

I have created this code to make a new field but the counter will not match if I delete an entry in the middle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Ta  bort</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what problems are you having - to code looks OK at 1st glance.

Comment: I added the information that you had issues with the counter to your question, Fredrik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is just for displaying purpose, use CSS counter:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x <= max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="count"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Ta  bort</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```css
.input_fields_wrap {
  counter-reset: count;
}
.count:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count) ".";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, i missed the significance of the numbers in the OP - good solution

Comment: Thats very good thanks :) I have one more question how do i add dropdown menu at the end of the text box every time i press add more fields?

Comment: @Fredrik What do you mean? How do you add another option to the select and remove it again every time you add or delete an item? You actually do not have this code in your question right now. Please update your question accordingly and make sure to describe EXACTLY what you need

Comment: I have that in my question i named it dropdown menu. I want to add a dropdown menu at the end of each new field

Comment: @Fredrik Just add `select` HTML markup in `append()`?! Is it what you mean?

Comment: @Fredrik I added a `select` after each `input` field, but still not sure it was your question...

Comment: Thank you @A.Wolff  and rest for awesome help :D